# I cannot make the oracle.dataaccess.dll to run in VS2010 using .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, odp.net

I'm trying to setup a web site in studio 2010, 64-bit. ODP.net is istalled,also 64 bit version. however when I try to build the site I get this error.
The project must be 64-bit, also my settings are for 64 bit in the project

Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. C:\Applications\DataConnectors\OracleConnectorWeb\web.config    10

My oracle.dataaccess.dll is visible in the assembly and I ca access the namespace. I know there is a lot of examples like thism, I have tried all of them and still have the same error.

I'm new to website development, however I have a lot of experience in desktop applications, even with oracle and the dataaccess.dll, but here I'm lost

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't use ODP.NET in the first place. You're tying yourself to a huge, hard to manage, non-portable client. Instead, use the Oracle Managed Data Access library that Oracle provides on NuGet. It's all managed code, so you don't have to worry about 32 bit vs 64 bit and it has no external dependencies.

Comment: I just want to point out that the "Oracle Managed Data Access library" you mention is also called "ODP.NET". There two versions of it, one unmanaged and one managed. I agree that if the OP doesn't need a feature that is only supplied by the unmanaged driver, they should give the managed driver a shot.

Comment: thanks guys I will try with the managed version on NuGet and see how it works